# C++ wrong std::string length when using constructor from "empty" char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-length

I tested this code snippet on different compilers but always got the same result, but I just can't understand why.

```cpp
unsigned char buffer[0x4000] = {0};
string strText((char*)buffer, 0x4000);  
cout << "strlen((char*)buffer) = " << strlen((char*)buffer) << endl;;
cout << "strText.length() = " << strText.length() << endl;
```

The output is:

```
strlen((char*)buffer) = 0
strText.length() = 16384
```

I'm creating a `std::string` variable from a `unsigned char` array (you can also use a signed char array, the result is the same). The array content is "zeroed" (use memset or C++ array initialization, depending on the situation) before passing the variable to the string contructor.

If you get the string length using C style `strlen((char*)buffer)` function, the result is '0' as expected to be.

**If you get the length of the string object using `string::length()` method the value is equal to the array size passed in the string constructor (16384 in this example). Why?**

Also, as a side effect, if you print the content of the string object using `std::cout` you get a very long empty string (all '0' are replaced with 'space').

Should I perform some additional manipulation on the std::string object in order to get the length I expect (0)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make `std::string` use the memory inside `buffer` instead of allocating own memory on the heap?

Comment: You explicitly told the std::string constructor that your string was 16 KB long. Why did you expect it to ignore that argument and produce a zero-length string?

Comment: `string strText((char*)buffer, 0x4000)` tells the string to be `0x4000` elements, regardless of the string contents.

Comment: the size is `0x4000` because you asked the constructor for that size. `strlen` looks for a `\0` but `std::string` can have `\0` not only at the end but at any position

Comment: if you ask `strlen` for what the size of `buffer` is it will also tell you `0`, but `buffer` has more elements. Its the same with the string.

Comment: for example `std::string s{"01234"};  s[0] = '\0';`  size of the string doesnt change by assigning a null terminator to any position

Comment: `buffer` is an array, not a c-string. Verify by adding this: `std::cout << "std::size(buffer) = " << std::size(buffer) << std::endl;`

Comment: `std::string` like standard containers manage the memory internally and dont let you choose where to store the data (at least not like that). If you want to be in control of where the string stores its data you can use a custom allocator.

Comment: `std::string` doesn't do anything special with nul characters. They're just like every other character.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: The size you pass to the constructor is not the array size, it's the size of the string you are creating. When you find something to be impossible to understand it's often because you are assuming something to be true that isn't. There is a valuable lesson here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor you use is this constructor (quote from [`basic_string` @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)):

> ```
> constexpr basic_string( const CharT* s, size_type count,
>                         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```
>
> Constructs the string with the first `count` characters of character string pointed to by `s`. `s` can contain null characters. The length of the string is `count`. The behavior is undefined if `[s, s + count)` is not a valid range.

---

You ask:

> If you get the length of the string object using string::length() method the value is equal to the array size passed in the string constructor (16384 in this example). Why?

Because you supplied the length to the constructor and a `std::string` can, as the wiki says, contain null characters.

> Should I perform some additional manipulation on the std::string object in order to get the length I expect (0)?

Yes, that would be a default-constructed `std::string`. Just remove `buffer` and the length when constructing the `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string strText;
```

If you on the other hand want `strText` to have *reserved* space equal to the buffer's space, call the member function `reserve`:

```
std::string strText;
strText.reserve(sizeof buffer);
std::cout << strText.length() << '\n'; // prints 0
```

If you want `strText` to only have the length up until the first null character in `buffer`, exclude the length (`count`) when constructing `strText` and the `std::string` constructor will read until a `\0` is found and `strText.length()` will be `0` in your case:

```cpp
std::string strText = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added a note about this too so it's not missed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for your answer. I misunderstood what the help says about std::string storage capacity and value retuned by length().  Moreover, std::string class does not take into account the content when returning its length, which is what strlen() does.

Comment: To answer other comments, the purpose of the code was not to create a string from an empty buffer, but rather pointing the difference from strlen() and string::length() when the string content has additionals null bytes at the end.

In a practical situation, it may happen that you initialize your buffer with zeroes, you pass it to a function (example to an external DLL) and then you need to check if the function filled your buffer with something. 

Now I know that I need to check the buffer content/length BEFORE creating the string object.

Comment: @AlexB. _"but rather pointing the difference from strlen() and string::length() when the string content has additionals null bytes at the end"_  - In practice, you may use a `std::string` (or other) suitable sized buffer as a receiver and _shrink_ the size after receiving "short" when passing on the result to another layer.